# Property [nama_kategori] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

this is my controller

```
public function show()
{
    $categori = Categori::all();
    $artikel = Artikel::all();
    $artikel_detail = $artikel;
    $artikel = Artikel::latest()->get()->random(4);
    $artikel = Artikel::latest()->get();
    $artikel = Artikel::latest()->get();
    return view('post.artikel_detail', compact('categori', 'artikel', 'artikelall'));
}
```

this is my route web.php

```
Route::get('/Artikel/{artikel}', 'web\PostController@show')->name('artikel.detail');
```

this is my file

```
<div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 blog_details">
    <h2>{{$artikel->nama_kategori}}</h2>
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include what you have tried to solve the problem, what error you are getting and what is the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should put parameter to method show

```
public function show($artikel)
```

Answer (score 0):

man, you have multiple errors, first of all you are no passing your "artikel" in your show function, shuld be `public function show(Artikel $artikel)`, then you have repeated things in your controller,  everything else seems right

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are several issues with the code above. Once you pass `$artikel` to show (or remove from your route, since you are only looking for the first), you can solve the error.  **The specific answer to the error**:

> Property [nama_kategori] does not exist on this collection instance

**is that you are pulling a collection, not a single model**.  The `get()` method is returning a collection of `$artikel` models.  To resolve this specific error, change your draw to:

```
$artikel = Artikel::latest()->first();
```

or

```
$artikel = Artikel::latest()->take(1);
```

This will produce a single model, from which

```
<h2>{{$artikel->nama_kategori}}</h2>
```

will not give you the error.